# Several systems have had an "ubuntu" added: where does it come from and can they be safely disabled?

Tags: dpkg, security, users, cloud-init

Background: on some hardware hosts that have been built manually, I use the installer to create a user named "ubuntu" with UID 1000 for initial setup. Our systems automation checks for an ubuntu user with UID 1000 and disables the login shell.

I noticed that many of our systems, over time, have had a user named "ubuntu" added through other means. The UID is in the 2000 range, conflicting with our LDAP users. I want to believe it is safe to disable these accounts, but I don't know how they got there, so I don't know what to test. I assume they were brought in via package installers, but which packages?

What is a good way to discover the provenance of these users?

Answer (score 2):

I started by looking for files owned by the Ubuntu user:

```
sudo find / -type f -user ubuntu
```

This uncovered a home directory.

```
ls -ld --full-time /home/ubuntu
```

This revealed an ISO datestamp. I studied `/var/log/dpkg.log` and found the date was consistent with "very early in the host's creation, before many packages get installed."

We are running `cloud-init` so I dug up our cloud config and noticed:

```
users:
  - default
```

Per https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html, "the 'default' user above references the distro's config" and then demonstrates that it would create an `ubuntu` user along with our other local users.